# Split column values into rows and preserve value from second column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having troubles with one of our tables, which i intend to use in viz tools. Maybe you could guide me on how to achieve below.

My table looks like this:

```
123 | ABC DEF
456 | GHI JKL MNO
789 | PRS
```

And I would like to split second column into rows and preserve value from first column:

```
123 | ABC
123 | DEF
456 | GHI
456 | JKL 
456 | MNO
789 | PRS
```

Could you tell me how to achieve that?
Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server split string"

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  There are some built-in functions in the latest version (and Azure SQL DB) that handle this.

Comment: Hi Vinnie, Just added additional tag. It's 2008.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: Never, ever store data like that. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `XML` node method to split the data :

```
SELECT ID, split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') DATA
FROM
(
   SELECT ID, CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(DATA, ' ','</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML) AS data from <table_name>
) a
CROSS APPLY data.nodes('/A') AS split(a);
```

Result :

```
ID  DATA
123 ABC
123 DEF
456 GHI
456 JKL
456 MNO
789 PRS
```

Comment: Works just fine. Thank you.